# Does Windows change EXIF header format?

Tags: windows, image, exif, explorer

I have created a small application in python which extracts metadata (like, dayTaken) from jpeg images.

Now if I change that metadata from Windows Explorer( [See here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows-vista/change-the-date-and-time-a-picture-was-taken)) , my application is unable to extract this day-taken field value.

For this, I opened an image file in a text-editor and noted down the position where the day-taken value was stored.

Then after changing day taken parameter from Windows Explorer, I again opened that image and I observed that after modification in date taken field, the format was completely different.

So my question is, does Windows 7 Explorer change EXIF header format and causes my application to fail in extracting metadata. Is there any work around to tackle this type of scenario?

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Sounds like your parser isn't working correctly. But, we have no code and no example to work with so there's no way to tell.

Comment: I am using this library to extract metadata. http://sourceforge.net/projects/exif-py/